# iOS: sign app for inhouse distribution with a customers provisoning profile

Tags: ios, xcode, certificate, code-signing, provisioning-profile

i'm having some troubles to code sign an app for in-house distribution. The customer got an iOS Enterprise Developer Account and set up a provisioning profile. However i don't know how to sign the app and if there are any prerequisites that have to be met.

Currently during the development the app is signed with via a profile of my company (the team  my Apple-ID is in). Testing devices are added via UDID to this profile. The next step would be to use the customers Provisioning Profile and Certificate to build the app for in-house distribution. I have the respective files but somehow i'm stuck. When i try to bring the certificate or provisioning profile in i'm getting code signing errors.

Can anyone help me with the steps i have to take?

Comment: you have client's mac system created cer .p12 file.? you have install this cer.p12 file in to you system?

Comment: actually i havent. i have the `.cer` file and the `.certSigningRequest` file (i have created this file for them). Can i create the `.p12`?

Answer (score 1):

If that provisioning profile crated by there system (Client Mac) and you want to use this provisioning in to you system you just need to its  system cer.p12 file and double click on it that instal in to you key-chain. Than you can use its provisioning from you system. No need to other stuff.

- just tel the client for sending its cer .p12 file like Go to keyChain and select cer that appear in to there system keychain.
- Just right click on that particular cer that pop-up appear like bellow screenshot:

[image]

- select Export Option and save. now Just you need this .p12 file in to you system.

Comment: First of all, thanks for your help. The problem is the following: the person in charge of my client has no immediate access to a mac (don't ask me why). Therefore i created the `.certSigningRequest`, he did the rest in the Apple Portal and sent me the `.cer` and `.mobileprovision`. I tried to import the `.cer` into keychain but i cannot export a `.p12`

Comment: then you need to all thinge again with new csr create developer and distribution cer create new profile id with new cer and crate new provisional with new cer

Comment: That wouldn't be different from what i did before, wouldn't it? Maybe the problem is i just have one `.cer` and i maybe need developer AND distribution cer? What do you mean by create new profile id with cer, think i omitted this step in my previous attempt.

Comment: BTW: i just saw, that i can select the certificate for code signing (maybe because i installed the `.cer` to keychain. However i cannot select any provisioning profile for my application. Maybe i need to add it somehow?

Comment: that install cer in keychain must with you system private key

Comment: :'( sir did yo see above screenshot ther left side cer with > arrow that consider you system private key it menas tha valid for your system. i am confused now what have you done so far and what are you trying.

Comment: Thanks for for trying to help me anyway. What i have done: i have created a `.certSigningRequest` (on my mac). My client created the `.cer` and `.mobileprovision` on a windows machine in the Apple Developer Portal and sent them to me. I imported the `.cer` in my Keychain. I wan't to sign an app with that cer (i think that works) add the provisioning profile so the app can be distributed inhouse (in xcode > target > build settings > code signing i can just select none as provisioning profile)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56200/discussion-between-nitin-gohel-and-patman).

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the enterprise account to generate p12, and then use p12 to generate the description file, so that you can sign the app.If you really don't understand.i can help you with the steps you have to take. Give me your email.
 I will send you a software, I think this can help you